# ExtJs: How can I select first item of Radiogroup on button click event

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a `radiogroup` and on button click event I want to set the first item of `radiogroup` to be selected. I have tried below code, but it is not working:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
    items: [
    {
                title: "Types",
                items: {
                    xtype: "radiogroup",
                    name: "type",
                    columns: 2,
                    vertical: true,
                    items: [{
                        xtype: "radio",
                        boxLabel: "Vertical",
                        inputValue: "2",
                        style: {
                            marginLeft: '10px',
                            marginRight: '10px'
                        },
                        hideLabel: true,
                        name: "layout",

                    }, {
                        xtype: "radio",
                        boxLabel: "Horizontal",
                        inputValue: "1",
                        style: {
                            marginLeft: '10px',
                            marginRight: '10px'
                        },
                        hideLabel: true,
                        name: "layout"
                    }, {
                        xtype: "radio",
                        boxLabel: "Auto",
                        inputValue: "0",
                        style: {
                            marginLeft: '10px',
                            marginRight: '10px'
                        },
                        hideLabel: true,
                        name: "layout"
                    }]
                }
            }
    , {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function (button) {
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name="type"]').items.items[0].setValue(true);

        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Above code is not working. I have also tried below code. But it also doesn't work:

```
var radioGroup = this.settingsFields.down(_.replace('[name="id"]', 'id', id));
radioGroup.select(radioGroup.getStore().getAt(0));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t7r)

You need to add radiogroup in query

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('radiogroup[name="type"]'[0].items.items[0].setValue(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the line

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name="type"]').items.items[0].setValue(true);
```

to

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name="type"]')[0].items.items[0].setValue(true);
```

check [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t7f)

Comment: It gives error: `Properties 'items' does not exist on type IComponent `

Comment: Its working in fiddle. But I don't understand why it is not working on my code.

Comment: have you set index as per the fiddle to get radio button check?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use id of your first radio item to select him
[here is the fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t75)

```js
handler: function() {
  var radio = Ext.getCmp('yourgroupitemid');
  radio.setValue(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to discourage you from using `Ext.ComponentQuery` and long strings of `items.items[]` where possible - If more radiogroups are added to the page, or things are shuffled around in the future, you'll be running around to patch it up and tweak which item[x] or radiogroup[x] the handler is changing.

I'd propose adding a reference to the default radio you'd like:

```
reference: 'defaultRadio',
```

And reaching it in the button handler by:

```
handler: function (button) {
    button.up("panel").down("radio[reference='defaultRadio']").setValue(true);
}
```

Which you can see in this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t8q) accomplishes the same thing, and is far more readable.

This will look at the panel containing the button, and find the radio with the reference `defaultRadio` that is contained within the same panel. This code would be easier to share within an application, and easy to change if you decide another radio should be default (i.e. just changing which radio has the reference).